# LINQ query and Array of string

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I have a  array of `string` say:

```
String[] Fields=new String[]{RowField,RowField1}
```

In which I can use the below query to get the values by specifying the values is query i.e `RowField` and `RowField1`:

```
var Result = (
    from x in _dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    select new
    {
        Name = x.Field<object>(RowField), 
        Name1 = x.Field<object>(RowField1)
    })
    .Distinct();
```

But if suppose I have many values in the `Array` like:

```
String[] Fields= new String[]
{
    RowField,
    RowField1,
    RowField2,
    .......
    RowField1000
};
```

- How can I use the query here without specifying each of the rowfield in the query?
- How can i iterate through the array items inside the LINQ?

Comment: Do you really need that many strings? What can you do with the anonymous type that you can't do with the DataRow?

Comment: I don't think you can as you still need to specify the property name for your anonymous type unless I misunderstand what you're trying to do here?

Comment: I agree This may be a problem which can be resolved by examining the what you are trying to solve.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve the requirement may be without using LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you want to retrieve specific fields from a DataTable without hardcoding the field names.

The following code will return a single dictionary object per row with the fields you specify in your array. There is no need to create additional extension methods or comparers:

```
var result = (from row in _dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                 let projection = from fieldName in fields
                      select new {Name = fieldName, Value = row[fieldName]}
                 select projection.ToDictionary(p=>p.Name,p=>p.Value));
```

The inner select picks the field values you need from each table row and stores them in the projection variable. The outer select converts this variable in a Dictionary

You can iterate over the result to get specific fields like this:

```
foreach (var row in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row["field1"]);
}
```

**EDIT:**
The above code doesn't return distinct values. It is possible to return distinct values without writing a special comparer using *group by* but the code is not very pretty:

```
var result = (from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                let projection = from fieldName in fields
                                select new { Name = fieldName, Value = row[fieldName] }
                group projection by projection.Aggregate((v, p) =>
                    new {
                        Name = v.Name + p.Name, 
                        Value = (object)String.Format("{0}{1}", v.Value, p.Value)
                    }) into g
                select g.FirstOrDefault().ToDictionary(p=>p.Name,p=>p.Value));
```

The Aggregate creates a new projection whose Name and Value properties are the concatenation of all name and value fields. The result of the aggregate is used to group all rows and return the first row of each group. It works but it is definitely ugly.

It would be better to create a simple DictionaryComparer like the following code:

```
    public class DictionaryComparer<TKey,TValue>: EqualityComparer<Dictionary<TKey,TValue>>
    {
        public override bool Equals(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> x, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> y)
        {
            //True if both sequences of KeyValuePair items are equal
            var sequenceEqual = x.SequenceEqual(y);
            return sequenceEqual;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> obj)
        {
            //Quickly detect differences in size, defer to Equals for dictionaries 
            //with matching sizes
            return obj.Count;
        }
    }
```

This allows you to write:

```
        var result = (from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                     let projection = from fieldName in fields
                                      select new {Name = fieldName, Value = row[fieldName]}                                                                                    
                     select projection.ToDictionary(p=>p.Name,p=>p.Value))
                     .Distinct(new DictionaryComparer<string, object>());
```

Comment: Thank you..but how can i access distinct values from it?

Comment: What do you mean? The sample shows how to iterate over the rows and retrieve specific field values. Do you mean how can you retrieve a specific row instead of iterating?

Comment: The method does not return distinct values :(

Answer (score 3):

```
var Result = (
    from x in _dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    select (
        from y in Fields
        select new KeyValuePair<string, object>(y, x))
        .ToDictionary())
    .Distinct(DictionariesComparer);
```

You'll also need to write your own `.ToDictionary()` extension method and `DictionariesComparer` method (as `Dictionary` doesn't implement `IEquatable`).

Comment: In tried with below code:  public static Dictionary<object, object> ToDictionary(this Enum @enum)
    {
        var type = @enum.GetType();
        return Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<object>().ToDictionary(e => (object)e, e => Enum.GetName(type, e));
    } But it gives me compiler error.Also Can you please provide me the correct code for  .ToDictionary() and DictionariesComparer methods?

Comment: @sharmila There was a mistype in my code - I forgot the second argument KeyValuePair constructor requires. Why are you trying to convert Enum to Dictionary? What is this enum?

Comment: `public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDictionary<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source) { return source.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.key, kvp => kvp.value); }`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help :) But The above code gives the error "Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class" I dont want the class to be static

Comment: Extension methods can only be defined as static methods in a static class. That's part of the C# language specification

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve the requirement may be without using LINQ?

Comment: Check my answer, I think you can do what you ask with LINQ without adding more code

Comment: @sharmila, `ToDictionary` method could be defined in any static class as long as it is visible from the code calling this method. Also, I'm deeply sorry of the mistake I made in my previous comment (I don't have a Visual Studio at hand now); the correct `ToDictionary` implementation is as follows: `public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDictionary<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> source) { return source.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.key, kvp => kvp.value); }`

Comment: @Panagiotis , I have checked your code.But some how it is not giving the distinct values for me :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no foreach linq expression.  I typically create my own extension method

Something along the lines of:

```
public static void Foreach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
{
 foreach(T t in items)
 {
  action(t);
 }
}
```

However beware if you're planning on using this with Linq2SQL as it could create a lot of db hits!

Comment: Can you please explain it ? How can I use this to get the desired output as in my example?

Comment: I'm sorry I believe I have misunderstood your question.  My code would allow you to do something like Fields.Foreach( f => Console.WriteLn(f)) answering your question about iterating inside the linq.  However I don't believe it will allow you to convert the array into an object.  Maybe the .NET 4 dynamic keyword would help?  I'm not sure I'm not that familiar with it?

Comment: what does action(t); do here?  can the LINQ expression can be written there? and how the function will be called?

Comment: The action variable is a method which is passed in.  In the example in my comment the Func<string> I passed in was Console.WriteLn (note that Foreach<T> T in this case is string).  You could equally pass in a truncate, reverse or any other method which takes a single string parameter.  The line action(t); calls whichever method was passed in on the T t.  However as per my comment above I don't believe this solves your array to property issue.  Just the iterate over elements in linq question.