# Linq query Group By multiple columns

Tags: linq

I have a array of string say:

```
String[] Fields=new String[]{RowField,RowField1}
```

In which I can use the below query to get the values by specifying the values is query i.e RowField and RowField1:

```
var Result = (
from x in _dataTable.AsEnumerable()
select new
{
    Name = x.Field<object>(RowField), 
    Name1 = x.Field<object>(RowField1)
})
.Distinct();
```

But if suppose I have many values in the Array like:

```
String[] Fields= new String[]
{
    RowField,
    RowField1,
    RowField2,
    .......
    RowField1000
};
```

How can I use the query here without specifying each of the rowfield in the query?
How can i iterate through the array items inside the LINQ?

According to some suggestions in [LINQ query and Array of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291902/linq-query-and-array-of-string) I am trying to get the result using the code below.

```
var result = (from row in _dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                 let projection = from fieldName in fields
                      select new {Name = fieldName, Value = row[fieldName]}
                 select projection.ToDictionary(p=>p.Name,p=>p.Value))
             .Distinct();
```

But the problem is it does not return the distinct values.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Start with distinct `DataRows` by using [this overload of `Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx):

```
_dataTable.AsEnumerable().Distinct(new DataRowEqualityComparer())
```

Where `DataRowEqualityComparer` is:

```
public class DataRowEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
    {
        return x.ItemArray.SequenceEqual(y.ItemArray);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
    {
        return string.Join("", obj.ItemArray).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```